# How do I run Intern 4 on IE, Edge, or Firefox on Windows?

Tags: intern

When trying to run Intern4 on IE, Edge, or Firefox (on Windows) I get the error:

BUG: suiteEnd was received for invalid session

Actually, IE works on Browserstack, but it gets that error when run locally (Windows 7 or Windows 10), or against SauceLabs.  I have installed the IE webdriver executable into Windows\system32.

I also tried running from mac, using a selenium hub and a node on my Windows VM, but that didn't work either.  Seems like Intern 4 internally starts selenium so it gets upset when you start your own selenium server?

Apparently the Intern self-tests run against IE but I couldn't get them to run out-of-the-box, they reference things like _test where there is no such directory.

Answer (score 1):

Intern supports various WebDriver targets using "tunnels". By default, Intern uses its `selenium` tunnel, which downloads the Selenium standalone server and required WebDriver executables. As you mention, there are a few other tunnels, including `browserstack` and `saucelabs`.

The `selenium` tunnel only downloads chromedriver by default. To download others, you'll need to tell Intern which drivers you need:

```
{
  "tunnelOptions": {
    "drivers": [ "firefox", "internet explorer", "MicrosoftEdge" ]
  }
}
```

You can also specify specific versions of drivers:

```
{
  "tunnelOptions": {
    "drivers": [
      { "name": "firefox", "version": "0.16.0" }
    ]
  }
}
```

To run Intern against an existing Selenium server or hub, use the `null` tunnel and point to your server using `tunnelOptions`:

```
{
  "tunnel": "null",
  "tunnelOptions": {
    "hostname": "192.168.10.20"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Hmm, even after following your first example, I can't run on Firefox or IE.  It does work on Edge though.  Firefox just stays stuck on the Firefox welcome page, and IE gives a prompt about opening an application (but I have to choose which application to open).

Comment: What versions of Intern, Firefox, and IE are you working with? And what is your host OS? (e.g. Windows 10 64bit)

Comment: Looks like I was running an old version of Firefox, when I upgraded Intern started to work.   But I still have the problem for IE version 11.  I'm trying on Windows 10 64 bit, but also tried Windows 7.

Comment: Have you ever used IE with Selenium on that system before? If not, there's some local configuration you may need to perform: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those steps.   FYI, in your last example above, my tests show that the "hostname" field is supposed to just be the host name, not a URL.

Comment: Ah, good point. I forget sometimes that Tunnel implements URL.

Comment: Thanks for the link about setting up IE.  That fixed it!